# Shopify display selected variant option

Tags: jquery, html, shopify, liquid

I´m trying to display the name of the currently selected variant color in shopify. I already found this code:

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  <your code goes here>
}
```

and the selector `variant.option1` but i can´t seem to get it working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Pure speculation but this probably the callback function for the `options.js` that handles the select field for the the variants. And it probably fires each time the select changes its value...so if if you use that `variant` parameter you will probably get the information for what you are looking for.

Comment: try `console.log(variant)` inside of the selectCallback and see what you get.

Comment: i tried var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
console.log(variant)
} but it also didn´t work. Is there anything that i´m missing?

Comment: Has that selectCallback function been used to create the option selectors?  There should be code like this somewhere: `new Shopify.OptionSelectors(/* CSS ID attribute of the select box that has all the variants */, {product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected:selectCallback })`